# Handling mySQL date formats when local date format is different

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

**Scenario:** My PHP application will always use the date field DD-MM-YYYY. MySQL obviously always stores dates in YYYY-MM-DD

**Disclaimer:** I know how to manually change the date formats - that is not the question

**Question:** What is a good, clean, elegant way to ensure that my application ***always*** retrives the date in DD-MM-YYYY, and mySQL ***always*** receives the date in YYYY-MM-DD to be stored.

i.e. Basically I want to have a single place where the conversion occurs ***automatically***, without me having to call it each and every time I do an SQL query. That way it doesnt matter if I "forget" to do a date_conversion - it will just always happen each and every time....

I'm thinking of some sort of callback somewhere?

**(edit) My idea:** I currently use the Codeigniter framework. I'm thinking of using MY_Model, using before_get, before_insert and before_update callbacks. In these callbacks, I can go through all the fields using something like this for a SELECT:

```
// {insert my query here to get records from DB. Then:
$query = $this->db->query();
$fields = $query->field_data(); 
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
      if ($field->type == 'date')
           // do conversion here
}
```

and do something similar for an UPDATE/INSERT callback. From what I can tell, there is no extra work on the database (because Codeigniter supplies the information in the $query result)

Thoughts?

**edit 2:** other idea: just do this for each model, and define which fields are date fields, and just apply the change at each callback... yeah... might do that...?

Comment: Sounds like a single function that looks for the first separator ('-') and returns PHP format if input is MySQL and vice versa.  Might work, if you remembered to wrap all dates in your function as the date moves between PHP and MySQL.

Comment: thanks geoB - but where can I put that? i.e. from what I can tell, mySQL does not have callbacks. So I need a function somewhere, where it will check all values, see if it is a date, and then test if conversion is required...

Comment: Are you using mysql_query to gather data, or are you using some sort of layered library such as Zend_Db?

Comment: I was thinking of a user-defined utility function tucked away in an include.  But if you're looking for something that looks at every field value from MySQL and every PHP variable I doubt the overhead of such a function is worth the effort.   How would you use this magic date function?

Comment: I'm actually using Codeigniter - I'll edit my question above to give you my current idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - answer to my own question - in case people search this and find it:

I am using Jamie's "MY_Model" - https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Use callbacks on each of your models which have date fields:

```
    class Fake_model extends MY_Model
    {
        public $before_create = array ('date_convert_to_mysql');
        public $before_update = array ('date_convert_to_mysql');
        public $after_get = array ('date_convert_to_php');

        function __construct()
        {
             parent::__construct();
        }


protected function date_convert_to_mysql($post)
{
    // Now convert the date field(s)
    $post['purchase_date'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post['purchase_date']));
    return $post;        
}

    protected function date_convert_to_php($result)
{
    // Now convert the date field(s)
    $result['purchase_date'] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($result['purchase_date']));
    return $result;        
}
}
```

You'll need to add foreach loops if selecting or adding multiple records. You could make it a generic callback which cycles each variable checking if it is a date - but it seems like alot of overhead. This way you just need to define the date field(s) once for each model

Comment: Careful with `strtotime`, it's amazing, but it will interpret AA/BB/CCCC as American notation but AA-BB-CCCC as Euro notation (eg will treat AA as month when slashed, AA as day when dashed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime to determine if the value being inspected, is parseable by php. If it is, then you can feel free to convert it

```
// {insert my query here to get records from DB. Then:
$query = $this->db->query();
$fields = $query->field_data(); 
foreach ($fields as $field)
{

    // strtotime returns false when provided an invalid value
    if ($timestamp = strtotime($field->value)) {
        $field->value = date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);
    }
}

// strtotime('Whatever content here') == bool(false)
// strtotime('2011-01-12') == int(1294808400)
// strtotime('January 12th, 2011') == int(1294808400)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP DateTime Classes:

```
// To Object, from input:
    $input_date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $input_date);

// From Object, to MySQL:
    $mysql_date = $input_date_object->format('Y-m-d');

// ... Do a query using $mysql_date, returning, say, "due_date" field:

// To Object, from MySQL:
    $mysql_date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['due_date']);

// From Object, to PHP/CodeIgniter friendly date:
    $php_date = $mysql_date_object->format('d-m-Y');
```

Or, a slightly cleaner version:

```
$php_format = 'd-m-Y';
$mysql_format = 'Y-m-d';

$input_date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat($php_format, $input_date);

$mysql_date = $input_date_object->format($mysql_format);

$mysql_date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat($mysql_format, $row['due_date']);

$php_date = $mysql_date_object->format($php_format);
```